# Vector256<byte> find index of byte with value 255

Tags: c#, simd

Given Vector256

```
<0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>
```

how do I find the index of byte with value 255 ? let's assume valid values are only 0 and 255

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;
public class C {
    public void M(char[] a) {
        unsafe
        {
            void* dnaLowerCaseBytes = "ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYXJOUBZ-._;;;;"u8.ToArray().AsMemory().Pin().Pointer;

            Vector256<byte> vecInput0 = Vector256.Load((byte*)dnaLowerCaseBytes);
            //<65, 82, 78, 68, 67, 81, 69, 71, 72, 73, 76, 75, 77, 70, 80, 83, 84, 87, 89, 88, 74, 79, 85, 66, 90, 45, 46, 95, 59, 59, 59, 59>

            var value = (byte)'M';
            Vector256<byte> vecCompare0 = Vector256.Create(value);
            // <77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77>
            Vector256<byte> result = Vector256.Equals(vecInput0, vecCompare0);
            // <0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>
            //                                      ^^                                                    
            //TODO: find the index of 255 in result var above ?
        }
    }
}
```

https://sharplab.io/#v2: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

Comment: I'm not sure about C# equivalent, but you're probably looking for `vpmovmskb`+`tzcnt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern C#, you can directly use AVX2 intrinsics.
Here’s an example, untested.

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;

Vector256<byte> vecInput0 = Avx.LoadVector256( (byte*)dnaLowerCaseBytes );
byte value = (byte)'M';
Vector256<byte> vecCompare0 = Vector256.Create( value );
// Compare bytes for equality, equal = 0xFF = 255, not equal = 0
Vector256<byte> eq = Avx2.CompareEqual( vecInput0, vecCompare0 );
// Move comparison results into a bitmap of 32 bits
uint bmp = unchecked((uint)Avx2.MoveMask( eq ));
// Find index of the first byte in the vectors which compared equal
// The method will return 32 if none of the bytes compared equal
int firstEqualIndex = BitOperations.TrailingZeroCount( bmp );
```

Comment: Thanks for MoveMask instruction! works great with TrailingZeroCount